# Detect exact version of IntelliJ from text-only directory structure

Tags: ubuntu, version, intellij-idea

I'm going through setting up a computer and wanted to see the exact version of IntelliJ I had on another Ubuntu computer that is in text-only mode i.e. I can only navigate the folder structure and run basic terminal applications.

Is there a way on the command line with Ubuntu detect which exact release I am using?

As an example, I am definitely using version 12, but how do I see whether it is version 12.1.4 installed or version 12.04.

Thank you in advance

---

The downloaded folder is called idea-UI-129.239

Comment: Perhaps the launcher for IntelliJ responds to the `--version` option.

Comment: When you start IntelliJ from the command line, the launcher is what you use.

Comment: no luck. `HeadlessException` because there's no X11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to IDEA root folder and output build.txt file by using `cat` command:

```
idea-IU-133.193$ cat build.txt

IU-133.696

idea-IU-133.193$
```

You will get last number of build. [Here](http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/IntelliJ-IDEA-Changelog-129169.html) you can find the version IDEA by build number.

Comment: @Crowie I'm sorry but I don't understand you. You may clarify what you want ?

Comment: @Crowie Why tomorrow ?

Comment: @dorortsevanton sorry for the delay